# If I don't want to use Broadcom drivers, what are my options?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.04, broadcom

I am having trouble with some wifi connections. Some questions I’ve read seem to blame the Broadcom drivers.

I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove  broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After reboot, it seemed that no driver was installed.

My wireless card is the BCM4313, and according to [Ubuntu’s guide for the Broadcom BCM43xx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#brcmsmac_driver_.28Open-source.29), I would need the brcmsmac driver. This seems correct according to [kernal.org Broadcom documentation](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211).

The thing is, I don't know whether I have to install it, or how. Apparently it should be there by default, but when I run:

```
sudo insmod brcm80211
```

I get

```
insmod: ERROR: could not load module brcm80211: No such file or directory
```

- How can I go about trying other drivers to see if any work?
- How do I install brcmsmac?

Comment: Try modprobe instead of insmod

Comment: @ubfan modprobe: FATAL: Module brcm80211 not found.

Comment: Have you tried the `bcma-pci-bridge` (or just `bcma`) driver? That worked for two machines I had/know about that used the BCM4313 (also, what is the output of `lsmod | sort` (please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/593283/edit) this into your question)?

Comment: @Wilf no I haven't but now I will, I'll report back.

Comment: Get yourself a usb wifi dongle. Rtl8192se works like charm. Plug and play

Comment: @Serg if this frustrates me enough, I'll guess I'll have no option, I would really like to fix it though, it's very frustrating.

Comment: What does this tell us? lsmod | grep brcm Thanks.

Comment: @Wilf I'm not sure how to install.

Comment: @chili555 nothing, empty.

Comment: Please try to load it and see what happens: sudo modprobe brcmsmac Does your wireless come to life? If so, I will propose a solution.

Comment: @chili555 yeahh!!! Awesome! Will it survive reboot, do I have to do anything else?

Comment: I will tell you in my answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21690/discussion-between-trufa-and-chili555).

Answer (score 3):

When you removed bcmwl-kernel-source, a blacklist file was left behind. It is preferable to purge, not remove. Let's remove the blacklist file:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

In some cases, upon boot, the driver b43 also loads and the wireless doesn't work. If this is your case, post back and we'll proceed. We may need to blacklist b43 or ssb or both; we'll learn with some trial and error.

Based on information derived in our chat, I suggest you compile the version of brcmsmac found in kernel version 3.18. Download this to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, with a working temporary internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.18.1-1
make defconfig-brcmsmac
make
sudo make install
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Remove the lines:

```
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

Proofread carefully, save and quit from vim.

```
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Is it working now? I will probably have one additional step.

Comment: That files doesn't exist, the only one that exists (similar) is blacklist-bcm43.conf.DISABLED should I remove that one?

Comment: Yes, please. Then reboot to test.

Comment: I can't make it work after reboot. Now it just hangs at connecting, doesn't connect fully.

Comment: What drivers are loading? lsmod | grep -e b43 -e brcmsmac -e wl Thanks.

Comment: [Here you go](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/trufa/c10fce7fddcebe30ff2e/raw/9d64a467d72b847f8299f2c4a74c24b8085bee9b/gistfile1.txt).

Comment: Any clues as to the problem here? dmesg | grep -e wlan -e bcma Shall we meet in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21712/discussion-between-chili555-and-trufa).

Comment: @chili555 In the comments below the question, @Trufa said `sudo modprobe brcmsmac` worked. How about to making that a .desktop file, and execute it on every startup ? Would that be a decent workaround ?

Comment: @Serg In our lengthy chat, we blacklisted all the Broadcom drivers and modprobed `brcmsmac` to no avail. We also dropped `modprobe brcmsmac` into /etc/rc.local to no avail. I'm stumped.

Comment: @Serg indeed as chili says.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with both Realtek and Broadcom. I solved the problem by using an Asus Easy N usb adapter. It was found automatically during install and works great at high speeds without dropping or slowing up on my Ubuntu 14.10 system. I know it also works the same way with Open Suse 13.2 and Debian 7.8
Hope this helps someone.